# Multiple Relationships to the Same Thing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I'm very new to rails so please forgive my limited knowledge.

If I wanted to create a web app for pilots to log flights, I might have the following models...

```
class Flight < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plane
    belongs_to :pilot
end

class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :flights
end

class Pilot < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :flights
end
```

However, if I wanted my Flight class to be related to an Airport class twice, one for the origin airport, and again for the destination airport, how would I do that?

Also how would I then set the relationship up on the airport side?...

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the class_name and the foreign_key options. You could try something like:

```
belongs_to :origin_airport, :class_name => "Airport", :foreign_key => "origin_airport_id"
belongs_to :destination_airport, :class_name => "Airport", :foreign_key => "destination_airport_id"
```

Obviously, naming is up to you. There is an example in [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to).

Comment: To add a little to @lucapette's answer, then one thing that is to note, is that the first argument in a relation in activerecord is the name of the attribute. If you have a column with the same name + "_id" and a model, you can skip the foreign_key and class option, if not, supply it like he does above.
Use the same approach for has_many for Airport, and you should be good to go :)